# Checking the parity of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I know how to check if a function is odd or even but I'm wondering if is it sufficient to check the parity of a function to evaluate it in a positive number and its corresponding negative?

For instance $f(x) = \sqrt{3x^2+1} $ is even since $f(-x)=\sqrt{3(-x)^2+1}=\sqrt{3x^2+1} =f(x) $.

Now a friend tells me that I only have to check it for a number, ie, since $f(-1)=f(1)=2$ then the function is even.

I am trying to think on a counterexample of this

Comment: Showing that $f(-1) = f(1) = 2$ merely provides a counterexample to the statement that $f(x)$ is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2(x+1)+2=x^3-x^2-x+3$$
Here, $$f(1)=f(-1)=2$$

But the function is neither odd nor even.